# Eastern characters in VS 2010 code editor

Tags: visual-studio

Anybody has an idea what the hell these characters in below screenshot are? Almost every key I press results in the characters in the screenshot. I get the issue very frequently (can't code 20 lines in a row without having it) and it seems to be triggered by intellisense use...

Seems I got it after installing the latest asp.net mvc 3 rc. But removing mvc3 doen't solve the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok, more precisely, it is triggered when opening intellisense by pressing ctrl+space. Opening intellisense automatically by pressing '.' does not trigger the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks as if you are working on a computer with support for multiple languages enabled; and that you have (Japanese ?) enabled; and you are triggering the language bar assistance in inputting foreign characters - which is done by looking at the transliteration of the foreign character into English, and then presents a choice of characters corresponding to that transliteration.  I would suggest you investigate the language bar, and switch it to English. The bar seems to have its own rules for location and visibility, and prominence. This is all assuming that this is a MS system.

Comment: Aha thank you! Your tip seemed to work. Apparently, after installing additional MS OFfice proofing languages i got the issue. Was around the time I installed mvc 3, hence the confusion. (didn't occur to me an office component could interfere with my VS)

Deinstalling the additional languages like chinese fixed it.

Comment: For reference (future google searches?), it's called IME (Input Method Editor).