# What is going on in VS2010? I have some asian characters poping up!

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can anybody tell me what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should write a bug report, because it sure looks like a bug.

Comment: I suspect this is some other software or plugin showing those characters which has nothing to do with VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the auto-complete/suggest window built into windows for far-east languages. If you have the language bar enabled (by the notification area) make sure it's set to English (EN) (Or whatever is relevant for your locale).

If it's not there, go to the "Region and Language" applet in the control panel, on the "Keyboards and Languages" tab, click "Change Keyboards". Remove anything you don't need from the "Installed Services" section, and set the default input language to English (Or, once again, whatever is relevant for your locale)

Comment: For reference (future google searches?), it's called IME (Input Method Editor).

Comment: I was going to drop that in, but I was fuzzy if IMEs referred to the method in general, or the dialogs with that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is identical to:

[Eastern characters in VS 2010 code editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173684/eastern-characters-in-vs-2010-code-editor/4173731#4173731)

and the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the answer given is correct. I offer the same advice, it's an IME related issue to change the input language.